# Will the array datatype in a Rails 4 and Postgres app maintain the order of the items in the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am curious about using the datatype `:array` in a Rails 4 app using a Postgresql database. Will the order that items are added to the array be preserved? My use-case is as follows: I want to allow three people to be added as `:collaborators` to a `Search` model. When I return the collaborators of a specific Search, I want to always list the collaborators in the order they joined the search. Is the `:array` datatype appropriate for this or should I consider using `:hstore` instead?

Comment: PostgreSQL has native support for [array columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) so the `array: true` stuff in your migration is a real array all the way down rather than some weird kludge like `serialize`. And you should generally prefer `jsonb` columns over `hstore`, more flexible and probably better ongoing support. But yeah, a join table with a `position` column, appropriate uniqueness constraints, and FKs is generally better.

Comment: Also, PostgreSQL does not allow (yet) `foreign keys` in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The array datatype preserves order, while hstore doesn't seem to guarantee it.

But also, maybe think about adding a proper collaborators relationship, if you want to link to another table.

Comment: Yeah, I think a join table is the way to go. Thanks for the response @art-solopov